# The Kronecker product of two $A_4$ irreducible representations and a decomposition into its symmetric and antisymmetric parts

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, kronecker-product

From the character table of $A_4$, I understand the following Kronecker products hold:
\begin{align}
 {\bf 3} \times {\bf 3} = {\bf 1} + {\bf 1}_1 + {\bf 1}_2 + {\bf 3} + {\bf 3}.
\end{align}

However, a physics textbook which I use also suddenly says it can be decomposed into its symmetric and antisymmetric parts as:
\begin{align}
({\bf 3} \times {\bf 3})_{\rm sym} &= {\bf 1} + {\bf 1}_1 + {\bf 1}_2 + {\bf 3}, \\
({\bf 3} \times {\bf 3})_{\rm antisym} &= {\bf 3},
\end{align}
and actually I cannot understand what it does mean.

First, I guess the ${\bf 3}$ itself cannot be decomposed into those two parts because if we construct symmetric and antisymmetric matrices from one irreducible representation $M(g)$ (acts on a vector space $V$ and $g$ is a group element) by hand like
\begin{align}
 M_{[\rm sym]} = \frac{1}{2}(M + M^t), ~~ M_{[\rm antisym]} = \frac{1}{2}(M - M^t),
\end{align}
these matrices do not satisfy the definiton of representation.

Hence I guess there is a way to construct two parts from two ${\bf 3}$s, but I do not understand it.

**My question: How should I understand the above decomposition?**

Also, I'm wondering why a ${\bf 6}$ representation does not appear here. Although it is not a irreducible representation of $A_4$, but if we divide the product space (which is the representation space of ${\bf 3} \times {\bf 3}$) into symmetric and anti-symmetric spaces, the dimensions become $6$ and $3$, respectively.
In the representation theory of ${\rm SU}(3)$, there is a famous (but I do not fully understand) decomposition ${\bf 3} \times {\bf 3} = {\bf 6} + {\bf 3}^*$. Is there any relation with this and the above decomposition?

I'm sorry for the rambling question.

Comment: Your matrices $M(g)$ are 3x3 matrices, but you need 9x9 when looking at the tensor product of the 3-dimensional representation with itself. Anyway, if $x_1,x_2,x_3$ is a basis of the 3d representation of $A_4$ $V$ then the 9-dimensional space is $V\otimes V$. Its symmetric part is spanned by $x_i\otimes x_i, i=1,2,3,$ together with  the symmetric tensors $x_1\otimes x_2+x_2\otimes x_1$, $x_1\otimes x_3+x_3\otimes x_1$, $x_2\otimes x_3+x_3\otimes x_2$. These span a 6-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V\otimes V$ that you can easily see to be stable under the action of the group.

Comment: (cont'd) The antisymmetric tensors $x_1\otimes x_2-x_2\otimes x_1$, $x_1\otimes x_3-x_3\otimes x_1$, $x_2\otimes x_3-x_3\otimes x_2$ span another subspace stable under the group action.

Comment: Yes, the tensor product $V(\lambda_1)\otimes V(\lambda_1$ of the defining 3-dimensional representation $V(\lambda_1$ of $SU(3)$ similarly splits into a sum of of the symmetric tensors, isomorphc to the 6-dimensional irreducible representation $V(2\lambda_1)$, and the antisymmetric part $V(\lambda_2)$ that happens to be isomorphic to the dual of the defining representation. In the case of the finite group $A_4$ the symmetric part of the 2-fold tensor product is not irreducible. Hardly a surprise given that the irreducible reps of $A_4$ have dimensions $1,1,1$ and $3$.

Comment: The general theme is that if $V$ is a rep of a group, then the symmetic part of $V\otimes V$ is always a subrep of $V\otimes V$ as is the antisymmetric part. With higher order tensor powers like $V\otimes V\otimes V$ the situation becomes more complicated. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320908/11619) for a bit more about that.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, the point is the 9 dimensional product space $V^2 \equiv V \otimes V$ is decomposed into the two (symmetric and antisymmetric) subspaces $S(V^2), \Lambda(V^2)$ whose dimension is $6$ and $3$, respectively. The symmetric representation is defined as the representation on $S(V^2)$. Although you wrote that the six dimensional representation is reducible for the $A_4$ case and I agree with that, but why there remains only one ${\bf 3}$ in the $({\bf 3} \times {\bf 3})_{\rm sym}$? Isn't it ${\bf 6} = {\bf 3} \oplus {\bf 3}$?

Comment: @Shaun Pierre Ramond's textbook "GROUP THEORY A Physicist's Survery". Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: Multiplicities of irreducibles as components can be computed with the inner products of characters (in the case of finite groups), so that is an easy way of verifying that $S^2V$  has $V$ as a summand of multiplicity one only. A different argument is that For $A_4$ the 3-dimensional rep $V$ is isomorphic to its dual. Therefore $V\otimes V$ is isomorphic to $V\otimes V^*\simeq Hom(V,V)$. The latter has the $G$-isomorphicm $V\to V$ spanning a 1-dimensional trivial representation. By Schur's lemma with multiplicity one only. It follows that $V\otimes V$ has other 1-dimensional components also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, the multiplicities can be determined by the character table so I understand for instance the regular rep. of $A_4$ is ${\bf 1}+{\bf 1}_1+{\bf 1}_2 + {\bf 3} + {\bf 3} + {\bf 3}$ or $({\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3}) = {\bf 1}+{\bf 1}_1+{\bf 1}_2 + {\bf 3} + {\bf 3} $. However I don't understand the dimension of $S^2 V$ does not agree with that of ${\bf 3} \subset ({\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3})_{\rm sym}$. Does it mean that the  ${\bf 3} \subset ({\bf 3} \otimes {\bf 3})_{\rm sym}$ is realized on a 3-dimensional subspace of $S^2 V$?

Comment: (continued) In other words, the matrix rep. of ${\bf 3}$ does act on the 6d space $S^2 V$ but it has only rank 3. Is it correct? I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I was too confused. For the six-dimensional space $A_4$ is represented as ${\bf 1} + {\bf 1}_1 + {\bf 1}_2 +{\bf 3}$ (=6). I understood, thank you very much!