# Is the highest weight space of $V^{\otimes k}$ an irreducible representation of $S_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, reductive-groups

Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with given action of $GL_n$. Let $W_\lambda$ be the highest weight space of weight $\lambda$ in $V^{\otimes k}$. Is $W_\lambda$ an irreducible $S_k$ representation?

This should follow from Schur-Weyl duality, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the highest weight of $V$. It should be clear that the highest weight space of $V^{\otimes k}$ is $V^{\otimes k}_\mu$ (so $\lambda = k\mu$). This is 1-dimensional and so irreducible. No need for Schur-Weyl duality except to clarify that this is preserved under the action of $S_k$.

Edit:
To make it even clearer why the highest weight space is $V^{\otimes k}_\mu$ consider the following: $V = \bigoplus_{\omega} V_\omega$ so $V^{\otimes k} = \bigoplus_{\omega_1,\dots,\omega_k} V_{\omega_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes V_{\omega_k}$ where $\omega, \omega_1,\dots,\omega_k $ range over all the weights of $V$. Note that $V_{\omega_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes V_{\omega_k} \leq W_{\omega_1+\cdots+\omega_k}$. Then since all of our summands live in specific weights spaces and they span the whole space we can easily conclude that:
$$W_\nu = \bigoplus_{\omega_1+\cdots+\omega_k = \nu}V_{\omega_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes V_{\omega_k} $$
The highest possible weight that we see this way is $ \lambda = k\mu $ and the only one of the summands which has that weight is $V^{\otimes k}_\mu$.

While there are are multiple irreducible subrepresentations each with its own highest weight these weights are different in general and thus $S_k$ does not move between these since its action preserves weight spaces. Thus the span of all of these weight spaces is certainly not an irreducible representation.

Edit2:
Note in general that a non-irreducible representation doesn't have to have a highest weight but this one does. It is not too hard to see that $(\omega_1+\cdots+\omega_k) \leq k\mu $ since $ \omega\leq \mu$ for all weights of $V$.

Edit3:
From some of your comments I think I'm starting to see where your confusion arises. $\lambda$ is commonly used as notation for weights but also for partitions. These are not the same things however. Schur-Weyl is usually written in terms of partitions:

$$ V^{\otimes k} = \bigoplus_{|\lambda|=k} V_\lambda \otimes W_\lambda$$
Here $W_\lambda$ is an irreducible $S_k$-module corresponding to the partition $\lambda$. Meanwhile $ V_\lambda $ is an irreducible $GL(n)$-module although we may need to think a little harder to find out what $V_\lambda$ is since we haven't been given its highest weight (at least not explicitly). Together $V_\lambda \otimes W_\lambda$ is called an isotypic component. The highest weight space of $V_\lambda$ is 1 dimensional so the highest weight space of $V_\lambda \otimes W_\lambda$ is isomorphic to $ W_\lambda$ and is an irreducible $S_k$-module (always - no condition on the partition needed). Of course the highest weight in one component may appear as a non-highest weight in another component but your stated condition ($\lambda$ having at most $n$ parts) certainly doesn't pick out the cases where this doesn't happen. For example, the partition $(1,1,\dots,1)$ corresponds to the symmetric power $S^k V$ which is where the highest weight I mention in my first answer lives. In that case the whole weight space is irreducible since it is 1-dimensional as mentioned. Meanwhile $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 4}$ has a submodule corresponding to the partition $\{2,2\}$ which is trivial as a $GL(n)$-module so the highest weight is $0$ and this weight is found in every other component and so the $0$ weight space is certainly not irreducible as an $S_k$-module.

Comment: Why $V_\mu^{\otimes k} = W_\lambda$? You have shown $\subseteq$ inclusion only. Space $V^{\otimes k}$ can contain multiple isomorphic $GL(n)$-irreps (Schur-Weyl duality specifies multiplicities), hence multiple highest weight spaces.

Comment: @SimB4 I've expanded my answer to explain why that is the case.

Comment: @SimB4 Callum did it right, I think. $V^{\otimes k}$ usually is not irreducible, but its highest weight space is a $1$-dimensional trivial representation of $S_k$. If you want to know about the highest weight spaces of subrepresentations of $V^{\otimes k}$ other than $V_{k\mu}$ then you could (should?) make that clearer. I'm afraid I'm not the right guy to explain it all. Though I managed the case $n=k=3$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320908/11619). At least in that case the claim held for the other simple subrepresentations as well (I think that's what Schur-Weyl is saying).

Comment: (cont'd) More precisely, I think that what Schur-Weyl is saying is that if we decompose $V^{\otimes k}$ into isotypic components as $GL_n$-modules (or as $S_k$-modules!), they have the form $V_\ell\otimes W_\ell$, where $\ell$ is a partition of $k$, $W_\ell$ is the corresponding irreducible representation of $S_k$, and $V_\ell=V_{\mu_\ell}$ is the matching highest weight module of $GL_n$ of highest weight $\mu_\ell$. Then the highest weight of that isotypic component seems to, indeed, be an irreducible representation of $S_k$.

Comment: (cont'd) You see in the $k=3$ example how all the three irreducible reps of $S_3$ appear as highest weight spaces of an isotypic component inside $V^{\otimes 3}$.

Comment: Alas, I'm not very conversant with that theory (Schur-Weyl). Hopefully somebody can say more. Anyway, the way you phrased the question it was, in my opinion, reasonable for Callum to interpret it as discussing the highest weight space of all of $V^{\otimes k}$ as opposed to the highest weight space of *an isotypic component only*.

Comment: Anyway, in the $n=k=3$ case the space $V^{\otimes 3}$ splits into $GL_3$-modules as
$$V(3\lambda_1)\oplus\left( V(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\oplus V(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\right)\oplus V(0).$$ In that case the highest weight space of $V(3\lambda_1)$ is the 1-dimensional trivial representation of $S_3$, the highest weight space of the isotypic component consisting of two copies of the adjoind representation of $GL_3$ is the usual $2$-dimensional irreducible representation of $S_3$, and the 1-dimensional highest weight space of the $V(0)$ affords the sign character of $S_3$.

Comment: ^^ My 2nd comment in this exchange should have said. *The highest weight* **space** *of that isotypic ...*

Comment: Duh. Of course the highest weight space of a Schur-Weyl component $V_\ell\otimes W_\ell$ is isomorphic to $W_\ell$ as an $S_k$-module, and hence irreducible.

Comment: @Callum thanks for replies. As far as I understand, in general $W_\lambda$ is not an irreducible representation. But is it the case if $\lambda = n \times k = (k^n)$?

Comment: @SimB4 If by $W_\lambda$ you mean a general weight space then yes they are not all irreducible. The highest weight space ($k\mu$) overall is 1-dimensional so automatically irreducible and the highest weight space in any isotypic component is irreducible. Although note that the weight there may appear in other components so that doesn't make the whole weight space for that weight irreducible necessarily.

Comment: @Callum I messed up a bit, sorry. Clearly, that $W_\lambda$ is not irreducible $GL(k)$ representation in general. The statement I want to reprove is that the space $W_\lambda$ of highest weight vectors of weight $\lambda$ is an irreducible $S_k$ representation. Your answer states it is not. The paper I read states it is, due to Schur-Weyl duality in case $\lambda$ is partition of $k$ into at most $n$ parts.

Comment: @SimB4 I know we are talking about the $S_k$ action. No weight space can possibly be preserved under the $GL(n)$ action. I can only imagine that the paper you are referring to is talking about the highest weight space of an isotypic component when they say "space $W_\lambda$ of highest weight vectors of weight $\lambda$". The proof is then exactly what Jyrki has said in his comments and is more or less just a rephrasing of the Schur-Weyl duality result.

Comment: I will say that I think that notation is confusing. $\lambda$ shouldn't be both a weight and a partition. In some sense a given partition of $k$ will tell you what the highest weight of the corresponding isotypic component is but they are really different things.

Comment: @SimB4 I've added another edit to my answer to explain this in even more detail

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and Callum, It's never late to thank you for your effort in explanations, this conversation was very useful.