# A question about the vector space representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simplex complex Lie algebra. Looking at this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407231/do-weight-vectors-live-between-the-highest-and-lowest-weights) we see that the weights of the non-zero weight vectors of an irreducible $\frak{g}$-module $V$ have weights strictly less than that of the highest weight vector of $V$. However this does not seem to work for the vector space representation of $\frak{sl}_3$. It is a three-dimensional module with highest weight $\pi_1$ and lowest weight $-\pi_2$ and the remaining weight $\pi_2 - \pi_1$. With respect to the partial order on weights we do not have that $\pi_2 - \pi_1$ is less than $\pi_1$ since
$$
\pi_1 - (\pi_2 - \pi_1) = 2\pi_1 - \pi_2.
$$
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If $2\pi_1-\pi_2<0$, then $\pi_1$ wasn't the highest weight, was it?

Comment: I think I see my mistake, I have mixed up the definition of the partial order on weights. It should be expressed a difference is a positive sum of roots not weights!

Comment: That's correct @Zoltan. $2\pi_1-\pi_2$ is a positive root. Just in case you haven't seen pictures of it: The weight diagram of this representation is the top picture in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320908/11619). A difference is that I call $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ (following Humphreys's book) what you call $\pi_1,\pi_2$.