# Does this type of tensor appear anywhere?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, tensors

Antisymmetric, or skew-symmetric tensors on a subset of indices are those that get multiplied by $-1$ when any of the indices from the subset are transposed. This type of tensor is widely used in physics and mathematics.

Now imagine I have, say, a tensor of type $(3, 0)$ that gets multiplied by $e^{2\pi i\over3}$ when I apply a cyclic permutation to the indices. More generally, let $h$ be an element of order $k$ in the multiplicative group of the underlying field, and say there is a tensor that gets multiplied by $h$ when a certain permutation of order $k$ is applied to its indices. This property does not seem to depend on the choice of basis. Do such tensors appear anywhere in physics or mathematics?

I'm sorry if this question isn't well-motivated, I'm just curious.

Comment: Apparently, The Wolfram Language specifically includes the ability to apply permutations to tensors which then multiply your tensor by a chosen root of unity. I can't seem to find any specific applications for this functionality though. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorTranspose.html?view=all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the space $\Bbb V^{\otimes n} = \Bbb V \otimes \cdots \otimes \Bbb V$ of $n$-tensors on $\Bbb V$ by permutation of indices, and this observation is a natural starting point for the study of Weyl's construction, [Schur functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor), and related ideas, one important consequence of which is the decomposition of $\Bbb V^{\otimes n}$ into irreducible $\operatorname{GL}(\Bbb V)$-representations. For more about this perspective, see, e.g., Fulton & Harris' *Representation Theory*, $\S$6.

Suppose that $\Bbb V$ is a (finite-dimensional, complex) vector space, let $\sigma$ denote the index permutation $(123)$, so that $(T \cdot \sigma)^{ijk} = T^{jki}$, and denote $\zeta := e^{2 \pi i / 3}$. In this notation we're looking for a description of the space $\Bbb S \subseteq \Bbb V^{\otimes 3}$ comprising the tensors satisfying $$T \cdot \sigma = \zeta T .$$ By construction $\Bbb S$ is a $GL(\Bbb V)$-representation, hence it is a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations of $\Bbb V^{\otimes 3}$. It's straightforward to check that any totally symmetric or totally antisymmetric tensor in $\Bbb S$ is $\{0\}$. We can similarly consider $\Bbb S'$ comprising the tensors satisfying $T \cdot \sigma = \zeta^2 T$, and direct computation gives that $\Bbb S'$ has trivial intersection with the spaces of totally symmetric tensors, totally antisymmetric tensors, and $\Bbb S'$; complex conjugation defines an isomorphism $\Bbb S \cong \Bbb S'$. Counting dimensions gives that $$\dim \Bbb S = \frac13 (n + 1) n (n - 1) ,$$ and hence that $\Bbb V^{\otimes 3}$ decomposes as $GL(\Bbb V)$-representations as
$$\boxed{\Bbb V^{\otimes 3} = \operatorname{Sym}^3 \Bbb V \oplus \Bbb S \oplus \Bbb S' \oplus {\textstyle\bigwedge^3} \Bbb V} .$$
It turns out (see the cited chapter of Fulton & Harris) that $\Bbb S, \Bbb S'$ are irreducible.

For example, for $n = 2$, $\dim \Bbb S = 2$, and with respect to a cobasis $(e^i)$, and where we denote $e^{abc} := e^a \otimes e^b \otimes e^c$,
\begin{align*}
\Bbb S\phantom{'} &= \operatorname{span} \{e^{112} + \zeta e^{121} + \zeta^2 e^{211}, e^{122} + \zeta e^{221} + \zeta^2 e^{212}\} \\
\Bbb S' &= \operatorname{span} \{e^{112} + \zeta^2 e^{121} + \zeta e^{211}, e^{122} + \zeta^2 e^{221} + \zeta e^{212}\} .
\end{align*}

For $n = 3$, $\dim \Bbb S = 8$; see [Jyrki Lahtonen's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320908/155629) to a related question.